# JSDoc Documenting repeated properties in exported object

Tags: javascript, jsdoc3

I have several modules that all act the same way and export several functions inside of an object, like so:

```
module.exports = {
  a:function(paramA,paramB) {
    return 1;
  },
  b:function(paramC,paramD) {
    return 'a';
  }
}
```

They all follow the same schema (take these parameters, do things, and return this type). I'd like to be able to document all these files within the same file, so that documentation isn't repeated everywhere. The problem I'm running into is that if I create a `@typedef` with these functions specified, it is ignored if done like so:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} myModuleType
 * @property {functionType} a
 */
/**
 * @module A
 * @type {myModuleType}
 */
 module.exports = {}
```

And if I create an interface, it complains that the methods are not implemented if done like so:

```
/**
 * @interface myModuleType
 */
/**
 * @function
 * @name myModuleType#a
 * @param paramA
 * @param paramB
 * @return {number}
 */
/**
 * @module A
 * @implements {myModuleType}
 */
module.exports = {}
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the original `@type` annotation actually works, it just doesn't autocomplete as it should in WebStorm  after being documented.

This is being tracked at [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30206) for WebStorm as to when it will be fixed.

Edit: As of 12/18/2017, this has been fixed in a recent build of WebStorm and should hit the main branch soon.